# SELECT COUNT with HAVING NOT IN - SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql

I just want to **count** how many student users are online, but not included the account type "*Admin*" and "*Professor*", and this is my syntax that has an error

```
SELECT  COUNT(`status`) 
FROM `tbl_registration` 
WHERE `status` = 'Online' 
NOT HAVING accounttype IN ('Admin','Professor')
```

Comment: I wonder why you thought having would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need having (which mostly slows down performance)

```
SELECT COUNT(status) FROM tbl_registration WHERE status = 'Online' AND accounttype NOT IN ('Admin','Professor')
```